# ParseException: Unable to read next JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In Spring Boot, I am trying to use Spring Batch to read a JSON file having a 1000 entries, do some processing and then write the output to a CSV file. The issue occurs whenever I use a TaskExecutor to enable multiThreaded steps.
Code for my implementation of TaskExecutor

```
      @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
```

Code for my Step implementation

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
@Bean
public Step humanStep() throws MalformedURLException {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("humanStep")
            .<Human, Human>chunk(20)
            .reader(jsonItemReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(humanItemWriter())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

Code for my ItemReader implementation

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader jsonItemReader() throws MalformedURLException {
        Resource input_resource1 = new FileSystemResource(inputPath);
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder()
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader(Human.class))
                .resource(input_resource1)
                .name("humanJsonItemReader")
                .build();
    }
```

The format of my JSON file is as follows

```
[
{"id":1,"first_name":"Hendrika","last_name":"Glossop","email":"hglossop0@samsung.com","gender":"Female","car":"SALFR2BGXFH882836"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Batsheva","last_name":"Drysdell","email":"bdrysdell1@example.com","gender":"Female","car":"2C3CA5CGXBH086890"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Xenos","last_name":"Evered","email":"xevered2@independent.co.uk","gender":"Male","car":"2C3CCAEG5FH423486"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Worthington","last_name":"Oleksinski","email":"woleksinski3@unicef.org","gender":"Male","car":"3VWML7AJ7EM658490"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Dee","last_name":"Weston","email":"dweston4@tripod.com","gender":"Female","car":"WBA3B3C59FJ781374"},
.
.
.
]
```

The error thrown is as follows :

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException: Unable to read next JSON object
    at org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.read(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:84) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader.doRead(JsonItemReader.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 1, column: 24]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:741) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.read(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:80) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone give me an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries" Sounds like maybe the JSON is malformed?

Comment: It works when I omit the taskExecutor line from the stepBuilder.

Comment: I am not familiar with StepBuilder, but, it sounds like it might be sharing a reader across threads. Readers can't be shared across threads. The second thread may be attempting to read from the underlying stream while the other thread is also reading and could be causing issues. In practice you cant really parallelize json parsing(Unless you have a dedicated thread reading segments from the stream distributing to threads that might be parsing it further. This might actually be slower though due to thread overhead.)

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonItemReader` is not thread-safe as mentioned in its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonItemReader.html). So using it in a multi-threaded step is incorrect.